# In Java, If I change an object reference during a recursive call, does it propogate up?

Tags: java, recursion

For example I make the recursive call defined below. The method finds the kth element from the last. If found, it assigns the current node to the object I pass to the recursive call. For some reason the node kth is null. Can you not do things this way? And why?

```
public void findKthFromLast(Node head, int k){
    Node kth;     
    recrusiveHelper(head, k, kth);
    System.out.println(kth.data); //this is null
}

public int recursiveHelper(Node n, int k, Node kthFromLast){
    (if n == null){
        return 0;
    }
    val = 1 + recursiveHelper(n.next, k, kthFromlast);
    if(k == val){
        kthFromLast = n;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: 1st of all, a void method can't have a return statement.

Comment: @Quoi No, The recursiveHelper() method doesent call itself, it jsut calls recursive()

Comment: And second, the objects are transferred "by reference". But the reference to the object is "by value". That means, if you access `kthFromLast.someMember` it would affect the caller's object, but if you assign to kthFromLast - it will not.

Comment: what does the recursive method do ?  recursive(n, k, kthFromlast) -- where is the code for that?

Comment: Sorry guys I made some changes. I was just typing this from the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, that code shouldn't compile because `kth` is not initialized and so cannot be used as argument for the `recursiveHelper` method call.

Secondly, any changes to the references in a called method are not propagated to the caller in Java, i.e.

```
private void caller()
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append("test");
    calledMethod1(s);
    System.out.println(s.toString());
    calledMethod2(s);
    System.out.println(s.toString());
}

private void calledMethod1(StringBuilder buffer)
{
    buffer = new StringBuilder();
    buffer.append("calledMethod1");
    return;
}

private void calledMethod2(StringBuilder buffer)
{
    buffer.append(", calledMethod2");
    return;
}
```

Output:

```
test
test, calledMethod2
```

The reason is, in `calledMethod1` you are merely changing what `buffer` reference points to but not making any changes to what `buffer` reference was pointing when the method was called. In `calledMethod2`, you are making changes to the object referred by `buffer` and hence the changes are visible in the caller.

If you are someone coming from `C` or `C++` background, this is equivalent to assigning to a pointer argument in a called method which doesn't affect what was passed in the caller.

Comment: I'm not creating a new object though. I'm assigning an object reference to kth which exists in the parent calling method.

Comment: What matters is you are **assigning** to a reference argument (either by creating a new object or by using another reference) and that just doesn't reflect in the caller method.

Answer (score 3):

If the object reference is local to the method, then changes to it wont be visible to caller or anyone else.

E.g:

```
void caller()
{
    obj = new String("asdf");
    doStuff(obj)
    System.out.println(obj) // still prints "asdf"
}

void doStuff(String obj)
{  
   // obj is a local reference, changing it wont affect caller's ref 
   obj = new String("ghj");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void findKthFromLast(Node head, int k){
    Node kth;     
    recrusiveHelper(head, k, kth);
    System.out.println(kth.data); //this is null
}
```

You pass null to the method, whatever you do inside that method, outside this will remain being null. You cannot change the value of reference in a way that is visible outside of method doing so.